# How to match multiple objects by their keys and combine their values in array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [
0: {a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]},
1: {d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c:["er", "sd", "we"]},
2: {a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c:["cv", "as", "xc"]} 
]
```

I am getting an array of objects and I need to find out the matched key that is common in all objects: for example here **c** is common in all the 3 objects. So I need c with the values in all 3. There is a high possibility that there can be more than 3 objects in an array, it can be 4 or 5. In that case how to match the key and put their values in one array?

output: key c :["nyx", "lux", "poc", "er", "sd", "we", "cv", "as", "xc"];

I am able to get a match for 2 but am facing difficulties finding when the comparison is more than 2.

js:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  for (var key in arr[0]) {
    if (i > 0) {
      if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr[0][key].push(...arr[i][key]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This only works for 2 objects comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function when supplied a specific key:

```js
const f = key => arr.reduce((l, cur) => [...l, ...(cur[key] ?? [])], [])
```

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is used to accumulate all values where the object contains that key, using the spread operator to combine the original array and the current array.

If you want to have an array with all keys at once:

```js
arr.reduce((obj, cur) => {
  for(const i of Object.keys(cur))
    obj[i] = [...(obj[i] ?? []), ...cur[i]]
  return obj
}, {})
```

#### Edit

Given you want to find for a single unknown key that appears in all those objects, here's my approach:

```js
arr.slice(1).reduce((keys, obj) =>
  keys.filter(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)),
Object.keys(arr[0]))?.[0]
```

Explanation:

1. Start out with the keys that appear in the first entry of the array
2. Iterate through the rest of the array, on every iteration removing keys that don't appear from the original list of keys
3. If the output array is empty, there is no key that appears in all entries, otherwise there may be one or more, which will appear in the array

Which then you could feed the result to the `f` function to get its values.

```js
const arr = [{a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]}, {d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c:["er", "sd", "we"]}, {a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c:["cv", "as", "xc"]}]

const f = key => arr.reduce((l, cur) => [...l, ...(cur[key] ?? [])], [])
console.log(f(arr.slice(1).reduce((keys, obj) =>
  keys.filter(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)),
Object.keys(arr[0]))?.[0]))
```

Comment: I am not getting any specific key I have to find out first the common key which is there in all objects

Comment: @Akanksha so you're saying there is one specific key that appears in every object in the array, and you want to accumulate for only that key and its values?

Comment: @Akanksha (see the answer edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` for efficient grouping:

```js
const arr = [
{a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]},
{d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c:["er", "sd", "we"]},
 {a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c:["cv", "as", "xc"]} 
];

const result = arr.reduce((c,data)=>{
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([k,v])=>{
    c[k] ??= [];
    c[k].push(...v)
  })
  return c;
},{});

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array reduce with with a `Map` and at the end do `map.get('c')`

```js
var arr = [{
    a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"],
    b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"],
    c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]
  },
  {
    d: ["ry", "cd", "er"],
    e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"],
    c: ["er", "sd", "we"]
  },
  {
    a: ["we", "as"],
    e: ["we", "lk", "pm"],
    c: ["cv", "as", "xc"]
  }
];

const val = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (let keys in curr) {
    if (!acc.has(keys)) {
      acc.set(keys, curr[keys]);
    } else {
      acc.get(keys).push(...curr[keys])
    }
  }
  return acc;

}, new Map);
console.log(val.get('c'))
```

Comment: The array of objects is coming dynamically so I have to first find out the matching keys and then need to combine all the value in a single array

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

```js
const arr = [
      {a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]},
      {d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c:["er", "sd", "we"]},
      {a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c:["cv", "as", "xc"]} 
    ];
    
const result = arr.reduce((res,data)=>{
  const newC = data.hasOwnProperty("c");
  if (newC)
    return [...res, ...data.c];
  return [...res];
},[]);

const newObj = {c: result}
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following JavaScript code:

```js
function findCommonKeysAndValues(array) {
  const commonKeysAndValues = {};

  for (const object of array) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
      if (!commonKeysAndValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        commonKeysAndValues[key] = [];
      }

      if (!commonKeysAndValues[key].includes(object[key])) {
        commonKeysAndValues[key].push(...object[key]);
      }
    }
  }

  return commonKeysAndValues;
}

// Example usage:
const array = [
  { a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"] },
  { d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c: ["er", "sd", "we"] },
  { a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c: ["cv", "as", "xc"] }
];

const commonKeysAndValues = findCommonKeysAndValues(array);

console.log(commonKeysAndValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [
      {a: ["ram", "shyam", "kunal"], b: ["abc", "xyz", "wxd"], c: ["nyx", "lux", "poc"]}, 
      {d: ["ry", "cd", "er"], e: ["ew", "op", "re", "er"], c:["er", "sd", "we"]},
      {a: ["we", "as"], e: ["we", "lk", "pm"], c:["cv", "as", "xc"]} 
     ];
     var finalObj = {};
      var initialValue = arr[0];
         var MatchedObject = arr.reduce((obj, curr) => {
            finalObj = {};
            for(var key in curr){
               if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                 var result = [...(obj[key] ?? []), ...curr[key]];
                  finalObj[key] = result.filter((value, index) => 
                  result.indexOf(value) == index); 
               }
           }
           obj = {};
           if(Object.keys(obj).length == 0){
              Object.assign(obj, curr);
           }
           return finalObj;  
         }, initialValue);
```

Check this code in google console it will give the output as -
c: ['nyx', 'lux', 'poc', 'er', 'sd', 'we', 'cv', 'as', 'xc'];

Only c is common in the arr therefor it got c with all the values.